# How to remove and push array elements in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array element, for example

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

I need to loop into this array and get only the last element of an array. I want to add a some elements into same element by deleting the past element.

example scenarios

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{

if(a[i]!=a.length){
//getting last element of an array

alert(a[i]); // output equal to 5.
```

I need to  delete this array elements, and I need to add new element like this

```
a[i]=[11,22,33,44,55];

//then this a[i] should again goto  for loop and checking the condition and I need to get output as 55. 

}

}

}
```

Can u please Help me for this scenarios..
 my problem is i need to get a last element of an array,(its working fine). after that i need to empty the array, then only i need to add. this scenario should repeat for n times,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pop` method to remove the last element from the array.

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];
a.pop(); //would return '5' and remove it from the array.
```

Then you can add the second array using `concat` (or `push`).

```
var b = [11,22,33,44,55];
a = a.concat(b); //now a would become [1,2,3,4,11,22,33,44,55];
```

You can then print the last value(55) with:

`console.log(a[a.length-1]);`

Edit: To make this code easy to re-use, you can wrap it in a function:

```
function popAndPush(inputArray, addOnArray) {
    return inputArray.slice(0, inputArray.length-1).concat(addOnArray);
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
a = popAndPush(a, b);
```

Comment: its working, but i want to do this process for nearly 10 + times, how to loop this process upto count =10, concept is alway i need to get last element , when ever i got last element , i need to remove and add  new elements, this process should continue for 10 + times

Comment: sorry to disturb, my problem is i need to get a last element of an array,(its working fine). after that  i need to empty the array, then only i need to add. this scenario should repeat for n times,

Comment: @user3056220 I'm not sure I completely understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: there will be an single array element for example,  a=[1,2,3,4,5]; in this we need to traverse through this and delete all the element one by one, and getting the final element alone in one condition. then after getting final element in one condition, we again deleting the final element, now array will be empty. then we again inserting some fresh element into an same array. then this process same process should continue form top to bottom, now fresh element should goto the top and checking the condition again , like this it should go for some counts.

Comment: @user3056220 That's still a bit confusing, but do you mean something like [*this*](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/RC3P4/4/)?

Comment: No. actually i'm working on Post method concept in Jquery. In that My Doubt is there is an array with some elements,if we goto the last element and Refill the code means we will get some new array with some elements, again this code want to check the last element condition, again need to refill the code. it should continue until i stop. i will give one link as example http://www.micemalaysia.com/CompanyListings_MG.aspx?DirID=70&ctrycode=MY&name=Company+Listings&mid=447  for Post method. in this link for pagination there are using Post method. how to get the Data for page 2,3,... etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pop and push to do that

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
last=a.pop();
alert(last);
a.push(11,22,33,44,55);
last2=a.pop();
alert(last2);
```

Comment: its working, but i want to do this process for nearly 10 + times, how to loop this process upto count =10, concept is alway i need to get last element , when ever i got last element , i need to remove and add  new elements, this process should continue for 10 + times